# tinymce adding p tags automatically?

Tags: tinymce

Im using tinymce and saving it to a database.

When I edit the saved content using tinymce and save again, it inserts a p tag at the beginning.

Editing the content over and over again leaves a large gap at the beginning of the content.

DOes anyone know a fix?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

TinyMce automatically add "`<p>`" in new lines.
You can set this option in tinyMce initialization like this:

```
  tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      force_br_newlines : false,
      force_p_newlines : false,
      forced_root_block : '',
  });
```

Hope it will help

Fonski

Comment: `forced_root_block: ''` stops tinymce for constantly wrapping my `<span>` tags with `<p>`. Thank you!

Comment: Now it adds DIV tags instead :(

Comment: slott, I think this is a recent update in v.4 Try also adding    `invalid_elements:"div"` to wipe out the extra divs.

Comment: Have to make forced_root_block: '' in tinymce.min.js  also. This only makes stop adding <p> tag from the textarea in TinyMce editor

Answer (score 6):

For me it worked by making "force_br_newlines : true" instead of false.

```
 tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "textareas",
      theme : "advanced",
      force_br_newlines : true,
      force_p_newlines : false,
      forced_root_block : ''
  });
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: thanks. I wondered why the selected answer's not working for me

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that @Fonski answer is correct but thought I would update this for anyone else that did was confused as to where to put the code. I placed the following in my `_config.php` file to get it to work:

```
$defaultEditorConfig = HtmlEditorConfig::get('cms');
$defaultEditorConfig->setOptions(
    array(
        'mode'              => 'textareas',
        'theme'             => 'advanced',
        'force_br_newlines' => false,
        'force_p_newlines'  => false,
        'forced_root_block' => ''
    )
);
```

Note: If you just want to remove the p tag that automatically wraps image tags (etc) all you need to set is the `'forced_root_block' => ''` option.

EDIT: This advice is for those using SilverStripe, I posted this thinking the questions was SilverStripe specific.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with TinyMCE v7 recently and encountered this issue. However the force_*_new_lines does no longer work. After a bit of reading through the docs I found the solution [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/content-behavior-options/). Although the issue is already solved, I figured adding this for anyone else searching.

TinyMCE v6.1 and up use the following to for shift_enter behavior on every enter

```
newline_behavior: 'linebreak'
```

Answer (score 0):

From tinymce.js v4.1.10 code:

```
newBlockName = (settings.force_p_newlines ? 'p' : '') || settings.forced_root_block;
```

So the key to avoid <p> seems to be as stated before

```
settings.force_p_newlines = false
```

and

```
settings.forced_root_block = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

using @tinymce/tinymce-react with ^4.3.2 version
use any string in forced_root_block, but not empty string worked for me

init:{{
height: 600,
forced_root_block: "anything",
}}