# How to add a macro to an umbraco page when using the markdown editor

Tags: macros, umbraco, umbraco7

EDIT:

What I really need is an editor that'll allow me to write html directly and allow inserting macros.

I'm using WMD editor in umbraco 7 and need to add a partial view macro to the page.

The editor does not have an insert macro button and if I pasted the following code in the editor, it is not shown in the page. I think the markdown processor removes it from the page ; `<umbraco:Macro Alias="YourMacroAlias" \>`

How can I add the macro to the page ?

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using tinyMce which is by default used by umbraco

Comment: yes - our frontenders don't like the tinymce because it add additional tags to the code

Comment: tools used by tinyMce can be disabled from data type rich text editor.

Comment: okay do you mean extra <p> tag added by tinyMce? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841986/tinymce-adding-p-tags-automatically this is in file tiny_mce_src.js for umbraco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, the WMD editor does not support embedding Macros in the same way as the Richtext Editor does. You could raise a feature request at http://issues.umbraco.org and see if they'll add it, or you could take the source of the WMD from the Umbraco source at https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS and create your own version of the markdown editor based on it.

The way the Richtext editor does it is that it stores the macro details as a specially formatted bit of markup, and there's some code in the front end that looks for that markup and replaces it with the output of the Macro.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the developer section. Open the Macros.
In your macro there is a checkbox "Use in rich text editor and the grid" and "Render in rich text editor and the grid" check this.

For Using in Rich Text the option must be checked in the Data Type.
In the Developer section there is below Data Types, the Richtext editor data type check umbmacro.

In the Rich Text editor there is a "Insert Macro" Button, the 2 gears icon.

But for a markdown datatype there is no button, no support, An option is invent a tag a replace you tag in the template with somethings else. To come a bit near a macro functionality.

Comment: Sorry it does not help. The issue I have is that the umbraco is not using the default tinyMCE editor and its using the markdown editor and it does not have the macro button.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is I cant change the type to the rich text editor. I need a way to add the macro via the wmd editor.

Comment: yep the markdown datatype do not have a macro option. I think that's out of the box it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Markdown editor for less options, you can disable excess commands for the tinyMce too. Extra tags added by tinyMce can also be disabled, see at end

Firstly there is file in config folder named tinyMceConfig.config. It handles the options in all datatypes using tinyMce. Below is entry for macro

```
<command>
    <umbracoAlias>umbracomacro</umbracoAlias>
    <icon>images/editor/insMacro.gif</icon>
    <tinyMceCommand value="" userInterface="true" frontendCommand="umbmacro">umbracomacro</tinyMceCommand>
    <priority>62</priority>
</command>
```

Go to

> Developer -> DataTypes -> Rich Text Editor

There will be toolbar checkbox list. Select umbmacro from the list and save the data type. You will see the macro on the WYSIWYG editor. Uncheck all unwanted options. Also you can create new datatype say "RTE Lite" using property editor "Rich Text Editor" and use this "RTE Lite" where less options are needed.

[image]

**Edit:** Okay, if you do not like extra p tag added by tinyMce, go to "tiny_mce_src.js" file from your umbraco solution, search for `forced_root_block : 'p'` and change it to `forced_root_block : ''`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I really need is a text editor that'll let me write html directly inside the editor. It can be done in tinyMCE but you have to do it in the source view. If I can get the source view as the default view for the tinyMCE it'll be ideal.

Comment: I am not aware if that can be set, but will let you know if come across anything like this.