# Tinymce Editor Plugin adding p tags

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I have custom editor toolbar plugin which inserts html tags. The tag opens with div. Every time when page is saved or published  the editor adds a new p tag above it.

here is the image

[image]

IMG tag drifts after publish I see a new p tag is inserted.
The Img being replaced by an html before saving

```
    <p>
        <div class="ssimage_code"> 
            <img src="src_path0" alt=""/ >
            <img src="src_path1" alt="" / >
         </div>
     </p>
```

I want to see if it gets solved by replacing a p tag instead of a img tag. 
How do I access the parent tag from Node?
getParent does not work

Code

```
            ed.serializer.addNodeFilter('img', function(nodes, name, args) {
                var i = nodes.length, node;

                while (i--) {
                    node = nodes[i];
                    if ((node.attr('class') || '').indexOf('slider_toimg') !== -1) {
                        self.imgToslidercode(node, args);
                    }
                }
            });

         imgToslidercode:function(node,args){
          insertcode = '';
            node.replace(insertcode);
         }
```

What I am looking here is?

```
       node.getParent().replace(insertcode);
```

Comment: hard to get what you mean... question not clear... maybe you should add some code or post an example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: problem occurs only when you submit/publish, you should have a look at this code...

Comment: Hope that helps what I am asking

Comment: What I am thinking is to pace the html tags without wrapping inside a p tag. P tags comes from the image. I want to try I want to know hot to get the node parent and replace it

Comment: Ok,... Did you google your problem? http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=3878

Comment: AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841986/tinymce-adding-p-tags-automatically

Comment: Julo. you got me right. I want to keep option forced_root_block unchanged. Is it possible to access the parent from the Node.

Comment: heh... to me, sounds like your problem is the "force_p_newlines" and not the "forced_root_block", right?

Comment: No it did not solve my problem. I see a new line inserted every time I publish.

Comment: javascript is : element.parentNode to get the parent...

Comment: node.parentNode did not work on a filtered(addNodeFilter) nodes .